# DataJpaTest annotation usage[Spring-boot]

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

what is the usage of @DataJpaTest annotation when testing ?
do we need it with every db connecting test?

the test is working even without the annotation

```
 @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) 
 @DataJpaTest
```

why @DataJpaTest is used why it has used and when to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `@DataJpaTest` will configure an in-memory embedded database, scan for `@Entity` classes and configure Spring Data JPA repositories. It is also transactional and rollback at the end of each test. If we wanna disable transaction management, we can use:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

We can also inject a TestEntityManager bean specifically designed for tests which is an alternative to the JPA EntityManager.

```
@Autowired
private TestEntityManager entityManager;
```

Hence, our Test Class should be similar to:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class MyJPAUnitTest extends SpringJpaUnitTestApplicationTests {

  @Autowired
  private TestEntityManager entityManager;

  @Autowired
  CustomerRepository repository;

  @Test
  public void testExample() {...}
}
```

More details here: https://grokonez.com/testing/datajpatest-with-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

Use @DataJpaTest annotation

> 1. allows you to test domain logic so you can check JPA mappings and you can check queries
> 2. It also configures Hibernate, Spring Data and an in-memory database.
> 3. You can override the in-memory database if you want to reuse a real one.
> 4. It also provides access to a TestEntityManager bean. This is an alternative to the regular entity manager that just provides some
>      convenience methods that you often want to use in your tests